# How to open a fancy box with a dblclick event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, double-click

My question is in the title :
How can I open a jquery fancybox (http://www.fancybox.net/) with a dblclick event ?

Thank you in advance for your response :)

edit : 
I tried that but it doesn't seems to work and I don't really know why :

```
$("#id").dblclick(function(){

    $("#id").fancybox({
        ...
    });
    $("#id").click(); //Trigger click to open the fancy because dblclick doesn't open the fancy
    $("#id").unbind('click.fb'); //unbind the click fancybox event

});
```

The idea was to handle the fancy box when a dblclick is trigger, then trigger a click to open the fancy and then unbind the click.fb event to prevent the fancybox to open when a single click is trigger by the user.
Unfortunately, the unbind('click.fb') doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally get the question, but try this:

```
$('button').dblclick( function() {
    $.fancybox({
        href: '#fancybox'
        // other options here
    });
});
```

No need to unbind anything.

EDIT: Here is a jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/abqTD/3/

Comment: No problem. Updated fiddle link to a working copy. Fancybox wasn't loading on the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".fbox").dblclick( function () {  $.fancybox({
   'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
   'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
   'speedIn'   : 600,
   'speedOut'    : 200,
   'href': $(this).attr('href')
   // 'overlayShow' : false
   });
 });

...<img src="path/someimage_thumb.jpg" href="path/someimage.jpg" class="fbox">
```

I'm trying to do something similar but on a class. Trying to integrate it with [jquery image picker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/).

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery .trigger() method. this way you should have an another element like button for activating fancybox.

```
$("button").dblclick( function() {
    $("#fancybox").trigger('click');  

});

$("#fancybox").click( $(this).fancybox(){
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :  600, 
        'speedOut'      :  200, 
        'overlayShow'   :  false
    });
```

Comment: This does not work because it will bind the fancybox after a dblclick but the fancybox open only when a click event is trigger. So with this code, if I double click the fancybox will be handled (and not trigger because only the click event can open the fancy) and then the fancy will open at each click event that is not what I want (not sure if i'm clear... )

Comment: This solution seems ok but I must not have a separate button :)

Answer (score 0):

Use fancybox methods to do this.

HTML

```
img src="images/sample_image.png" alt="Sample Title" class="fancybox"
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').dblclick(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src'),
            imgTitle = $(this).attr('alt');

        $.fancybox.open({href : imgSrc , title : imgTitle });
    });
});
```

Hope this helped... ;)